# Geometry of Rejection regions for tests (NP lemma, Karl-Rubin, UMPU, LMP, etc)?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, geometry

The Neyman-Pearson lemma, the Karlin-Rubin theorem, and the other for UMPU tests for the exponential family, etc. They all define a most powerful Rejection Region (RR), in a certain class of tests.

I was wondering how do these RR translate into graphs? I'm interested not only in those tests that are most powerful in a sense, but also the usual tests we use, even if we don't do a power study of them. 
For example, when we use a Wald test of the form $n(\hat\phi-\phi)^TC^{-1}(\hat\phi-\phi)$ we get a quadratic. So, the RR we're interested in is the one defined just by a one-tailed test, i.e., an ellipsoid around the true value $\phi$, and whenever our estimates lie outside the ellipsoid, we reject the null.

It would be nice to gather as much examples of RR for different tests as possible.

Comment: In multiple testing (with e.g. Bonferroni correction) you get a rectangle in two dimensions, a box in three dimensions, ...

Comment: @fcop please write up an answer It would be great to be able to structure this. ;)

Comment: maybe you can help me with this @An old man in the sea ? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229193/whats-wrong-with-multiple-testing-correction-compared-to-joint-tests

Comment: @fcop I'm not sure whether I'm that capable. I'll have a look. Meanwhile, I've put +1 on it. ;)

Comment: I am sure that, at least, you understood because your question on the geometric shape of the acceptance region made me think and led to this question

Comment: @fcop But I'm not myself familiarised with multiple testing corrections...

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the Wald test that you mention and (for ease of understanding) limiting it to two dimensions, your test looks something like $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_{10} \& \mu_2 = \mu_{20}$ versus $H_0: \mu_1 \ne \mu_{10} | \mu_2 \ne \mu_{20}$.

You can approach this problem in two ways; either you can use ''joint tests'' or you can use ''multiple testing procedures''.  Joint tests start from a multi-variate distribution for a test statistic (the Wald test you mention is an example) while multiple testing procedures ''adjust'' the p-value (or equivalently , adjust the signficinace level).  The Bonferroni correction is an example of a multiple testing procedure. For more details see [this link](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp1885.en.pdf).

The Bonferroni procedure states that, if you perform two tests, then you should perform two independent tests, but in order not to inflate the type I error, you should do each test with half the significance level (or you should double the p-values). (This also holds for more than two tests).

Obviously, if I perform each of the two tests in a ''univariate way'' with half the significance level, then I find an interval in each of the two dimensions or a reactankle in the two-dimensional plane.

You can see the different shapes in the figures 2,3,4 in the link supra. Figure 4 has a ''combined shape'', for details see the link.

Comment: I liked figure 6. :)

Comment: I agree, figure 6 is a fantastic picture :-)